# Kotlin function return no changes

Tags: android, kotlin

i'm working on a project that needs to send latitude and longitude to an database.

But i'm with a problem in the return of the function, the function just returns to me the original value
(DBLatitude = 0.0 and DBLongitude = 0.0)
(the tvs are working properly and showing my current location on my app in real time so... maybe i am making some mistakes with DBLatitude and DBLongitude?)

```
   private fun getCurrentLocation(): String {
    var DBLatitude: Double = 0.0
    var DBLongitude: Double = 0.0

    if (checkPermissions()) {
        if (isLocationEnabled()) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                checkPermissions()
            }
            fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                val location = task.result

                if (location == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Null obtido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } else {
                    binding.tvLatitude.text = "" + location.latitude
                    binding.tvLongitude.text = "" + location.longitude

                    DBLatitude = location.latitude
                    DBLongitude = location.longitude
                }
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ligue a localização", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    } else {
        requestPermission()
    }
    return "" + DBLatitude + " " + DBLongitude
}
```

Comment: This isn’t an API, but it’s the same issue as in this question because it’s a listener that gets called in the future. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-or-launches-a-coroutine-return-an-empty-o

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my function that calls an API or launches a coroutine return an empty or null value?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70178210/9473786)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.addOnCompleteListener` is an asynchronous function. This means, that this operation will be performed in background and will invoke callback that you pass to it after the location will be retrieved.

You should pass a listener to this function, which will be invoked when `lastLocation` will be retrieved from API.

So you can achieve the result you probably expect now by doing this way:

```
private var latitude: Double? = null
private var longitude: Double? = null

private fun callerFun() {
    getCurrentLocation { result ->
           latitude = result.first
           longitude = result.second
           binding.tvLatitude.text = "" + result.first
           binding.tvLongitude.text = "" + result.second
    }
}

private fun getCurrentLocation(onComplete: (Pair<Double, Double>) -> Unit) {    
    if (checkPermissions()) {
        if (isLocationEnabled()) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                checkPermissions()
            }
            fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                val location = task.result

                if (location == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Null obtido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } else {
                    onComplete.invoke(Pair(location.latitude, location.longitude)
                }
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ligue a localização", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    } else {
        requestPermission()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mikhail, thank you for your help, but how can i save the values of latitude and longitude in a global variable?

Comment: Hi Bruno, check my updated answer

Comment: Thank you Mikhail!
 That onComplete.invoke(Pair(location.latitude, location.longitude)) 
was really amazing i never knew that things like this was possible

Comment: Using `onComplete.invoke(args)` is not necessary, you can just call `onComplete(args)`. See the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#invoking-a-function-type-instance)

Answer (score 2):

```
fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.addOnCompleteListener(this)
```

Is an asynchronous function. This means that it will finish its execution after your `getCurrentLocation()` function has completed and so therefore `DBLatitude` and `DBLongitude` remain unchanged.

Your best bet at this point is to make `getCurrentLocation()` return nothing and create a new function that will be called when `lastLocation` completes